# Overwrite response from api with python

Tags: python, api, response

I would like to get data from api, but api is presented in pages. So I have to iterate through all of them and save wanted data in variable.

I was trying to attach new page in loop and add data to my response, but only I got was error: "TypeError: must be str, not Response". I wanted to do it in this way:

```
response = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page=1"

for i in range(2,32):
    url = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page="+str(i)
    response += requests.get(url)

data = response.text
```

When I get the data I want to extract and operate on them.

Answer (score 1):

requests.get(url) returns a Response object. At the moment, you are trying to add the Response object to a string.

Try something like this:

```
response = []

for i in range(2,32):
    url = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page="+str(i)
    response.append(requests.get(url).text)
```

When that finishes running, response will be a list full of the response text instead of response objects.

Comment: Yeah, but at this moment I have list with data from each page, but I want to have everything in one variable not as a list

Comment: Do you want all the data.text combined in a string? How do you want them to be stored.